# insert in one DataContext, submit in another

Tags: .net, linq, datacontext

I have two `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` instances of same type. There is a table `Table1` in `DataContext`. I add an object in first `DataContext` instance to the `Table1` using the `InsertOnSubmit` method and I call `SubmitChanges` in second instance.

Will the object be inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The SubmitChanges call only looks at the changes logged in the current context. It will not know about changes in a different data context and won't submit them.  There are some things you can do that would make it appear so (like adding the object to a collection in on an object in the submitted context), but if they are truly independent, then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

My recommendation is to follow the repository pattern, which declares a single instance of the data context at the class level.  Scott Gu's NerdDinner, although it applies specifically to ASP.NET MVC, still has some good insight on how to build a data model using this pattern: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm